# Aggregating on a repeated group

Tags: oracle, aggregate

In a current report, I'm trying to track the migration of a person from department n, to n+1, or to n+k.

My data is split into a row per term (university data).  An example:

```
dept |  term
------------
   a | 20120
   a | 20121
   a | 20122
   b | 20123 -- <- person moved to new department
   b | 20130
   c | 20131 -- <- person moved to another new department
   a | 20132 -- <- person went back to a department they've already been in
```

using the query

```
select 
  dept, 
  FIRST_VALUE(term) OVER (PARTITION BY dept ORDER BY term) as 
from
  table
order by term;
```

gives me:

```
dept |  term
------------
   a | 20120
   a | 20120
   a | 20120
   b | 20123
   b | 20123
   c | 20131 
   a | 20120 -- <- notice this is the same as the above set of a's
```

The duplicated a's in the first group and b's in the second group are due to other rows in the data (I'm okay with this, but removing that would be a bonus).  My main problem is I need that final a to be treated as a different group; so basically showing the first each time a cluster appears.

Comment: Is your table named `table`? Anyway, this is a ["groups and islands" problem](http://dba.stackexchange.com/search?q=groups+and+islands). There are several similar questions in the site.

Comment: @ypercube only for the purpose of the example. The db we use doesn't store the database in a particularly awesome format. Thanks for the name of the problem, I will look into those.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This kind of problem can be solved with the use of the `LAG()` function:

```
WITH cte AS
  ( SELECT dept,
           term,
           LAG(dept) OVER (ORDER BY term) AS prev_dept
     FROM tableX
  )
SELECT dept, term
FROM cte
WHERE prev_dept <> dept 
   OR prev_dept IS NULL
ORDER BY term ;
```

Test at: **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c9912/7)**

Comment: Yep really nice

Comment: That is beautifully elegant.  Thank you for your help.  I will be looking into these sets of problems more thoroughly!

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to use some looping to do this as you have to define a group of records when the dept changes. I have written this in TSQL so you may need to make some syntax changes but it works.

```
DECLARE @Dept VARCHAR(1), @Term INT, @Dept2 VARCHAR(1), @Group INT = 0

CREATE TABLE #TempTerms
(dept VARCHAR(1),
term INT)

CREATE TABLE #TempTermsGrouped
(dept VARCHAR(1),
term INT,
[group] INT)

INSERT INTO #TempTerms
SELECT *
FROM [Dev].[dbo].[terms]

WHILE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM #TempTerms)
BEGIN
    SELECT @Dept = (SELECT TOP 1 dept FROM #TempTerms ORDER BY term), @Term = (SELECT TOP 1 term FROM #TempTerms ORDER BY term)

    IF @Dept <> ISNULL(@Dept2, '')
        SELECT @Group = @Group + 1

    INSERT INTO #TempTermsGrouped
    SELECT @Dept, @Term, @Group

    SET @Dept2 = @Dept

    DELETE FROM #TempTerms WHERE dept = @Dept AND term = @Term
END

SELECT  dept,
        MIN(Term) term
FROM    #TempTermsGrouped

GROUP BY dept, [group]

DROP TABLE #TempTermsGrouped
DROP TABLE #TempTerms
```

Comment: You would need more than 6 syntax changes to make this run in Oracle. (missing `;`, convert brackets to quotes, temp tables naming, add `FROM` to all the `SELECT`, find the equivalence of `ISNULL` and `TOP`  which is not trivial at all) and then wonder why the `<> ISNULL()` conditions do not work as expected.